# FadeIn / FadeOut make DIV's stack instead of overlapping? Using 'absolute' wasn't a solution

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently using the the following piece of code to fade in/out various DIV's (which hold information). This works, however I am not satisfied with the result. It should overlap each other, instead of piling up on each other.

I did a search and the only workable thing for me was to add: position:absolute; in the CSS. Though this works, it messes up the rest of the items underneath it. So I am looking to fix this.

I did read about inserting a so-called call-back function, however I don't know how to use that with this coding.

Here is a piece of the fade in/out code:

```
$('.extraInfo').hide();

$('input').on('ifChecked', function(event){
    var extraInformationId = $(this).closest('label')[0].id;
    if(extraInformationId != undefined) {
        $('div.extraInfo[data-extrainformationfor="' + extraInformationId+'"]').fadeIn(500);
    }
});

$('input').on('ifUnchecked', function(event){
    var extraInformationId = $(this).closest('label')[0].id;
    if(extraInformationId != undefined) {
        $('div.extraInfo[data-extrainformationfor="' + extraInformationId+'"]').fadeOut(500);
    }
});
```

The best thing I can come up with myself, other than changing the CSS to absolute, is by changing fade in/out from 500 to 0. However that's not really a solution. :|

If you need more information and/or details, here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5hvmzjzf/3/).

When you click on the items, you will notice the DIV's are stacking. This, in my opinion, makes things look kinda 'ugly'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `ifUnchecked` part and use this for the `ifChecked`

```
$('input').on('ifChecked', function(event){
    $("div.extraInfo")
        .fadeOut(500)    // hide all divs with class `extraInfo`
        .promise()       // "wait" for the asynchonous animations to complete
        .done(function() {    // and then show the info for the selected one
            var extraInformationId = $(this).closest('label').attr("id");

            if(extraInformationId) {
                $('div.extraInfo[data-extrainformationfor="' + extraInformationId+'"]').fadeIn(500);
            }
        }.bind(this));    // preserve the value of this for the callback of fadeOut
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eevjqbbL/)

Comment: Awesome man. Thank you, Andreas! This works even better than I hoped for. It also fixes the other options (those were stacking under the first set). You should get a double checkmark for this imho. Highly appreciated your help!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `fadeout`, use `hide`

```
$('input').on('ifUnchecked', function(event){
    var extraInformationId = $(this).closest('label')[0].id;
    if(extraInformationId != undefined) {
        $('div.extraInfo[data-extrainformationfor="' + extraInformationId+'"]').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: That is pretty much the same thing as fade in/out with 0 animation, which he doesn't want.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't have animation. Hiding and Fading are firing simultaneously. But hiding takes 0 time to finish. At the same time, fading is already happening.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by introducing some delay.Since checking & unchecking is happening almost simultaneously you are seeing two text before one get removed

```
$('input').on('ifChecked', function(event){
    var extraInformationId = $(this).closest('label')[0].id;
    if(extraInformationId != undefined) {
        setTimeout(function(){
$('div.extraInfo[data-extrainformationfor="' + extraInformationId+'"]').fadeIn(1000);
},1000)
    }
}); 
[jsfiddle][1]
```